# Изменение 4 элементов и классов при наведение на любой

Tags: javascript

Добрый день.

Есть 3 класса и  1 тег <a> внутри первого класса

```
.class_1 {styles1}
.class_2 {styles2}
.class_3 {styles3}
.class_1 a {styles4}
```

есть 4 результата при наведении - hover

```
.rezult_1:hover {different styles1}
.rezult_2:hover {different styles2}
.rezult_3:hover {different styles3}
.rezult_1 a:hover {different styles4}
```

все работает прекрасно, но задача состоит в том чтобы сделать так, чтобы при наведении на любой из классов или тег применялись все 4 ховера соответственно каждый к своему селектору.

Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Я бы поменял стили на такие

```
.class_1.hover {color: black;}
.class_2.hover {color: black;}
.class_3.hover {color: black;}
.class_1.hover a {color: black;}
```

И в `js` вот такое:

```
$('div').hover(function() {
  $('div').addClass('hover');
}, function() {
  $('div').removeClass('hover');
});
```

Примерчик: http://jsbin.com/UtoJexE/8/edit

Comment: Оk, на самом деле задача следующая

Посмотрите пожалуйста тут тут http://jsfiddle.net/e27Dt/154/

каждая строчка должна быть незавиимо от другой

В html таких блочков может быть на странице 5 - 20 я даже не знаю.

А они все получаются синхронные и Дивов тоже много на странице тоже переплетаются, тоесть думаю надо как то по классам все таки, но если есть другие варианты решения я не против.

Спасибо!

Comment: @Ruson У меня почему-то последнее время jsfiddle не грузится. Не могу посмотреть.

Comment: Cделал jsbin то-же самое =)

http://jsbin.com/ixACUDa/1/edit